# Angular 10 | FormControl in Dynamic Component

Tags: angular, form-control, angular-dynamic-components

I'm trying to resolve a simple task: dynamically load a component contains a form control.
Everything is OK except I get such error:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
> has changed after it was checked.  Previous value: 'undefined'.
> Current value: '[object Object]'. It seems like the view has been
> created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has
> it been created in a change  detection hook?

I load a component in a canonical way - in `ngAfterViewInit` hook with a `ComponentFactoryResolver` and a `ViewContainerRef`.

I've tried to google about this problem and search here, but I didn't found any clear explanation why it is and how I can fix it.

I'm new in Angular and I might ask questions in a wrong way.

I've prepared [an example about it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahfc8f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you commented out this part `<!--<app-my-form></app-my-form>-->` un-comment and use it this is the best approach

Comment: You can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42760546/10842900

Comment: @KamranKhatti
Hi,
Thanks a lot for your answer!
But it would be the best soulution, if I don't need to load a component dynamically from  vague number of components.

Comment: @Indraraj26
Thanks a lot for this link! 
It helped me with my trouble.

P.S.: it's really strange for me, that in the Angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) said nothing about that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not sure why that kind of error is coming, however `setTimeout` can solve your problem.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
      let factory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyFormComponent);
      let compRef = this.formSlotRef.createComponent(factory);
});
```

Another way is to use `OnPush` change detection strategy. It will not detect your change automatically but you will trigger the detection after the `view` is checked and your component is added.

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  @ViewChild("formSlot", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  private formSlotRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private compFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let factory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      MyFormComponent
    );
    let compRef = this.formSlotRef.createComponent(factory);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Indraraj26, which solution?

Comment: This trigger an additional change detection when you wrap anything in setTimeout we need to find an real issue that causing an express change error

Comment: yeah so added another solution too for checking the detection manually

Comment: That will also call additional change detection. It is causing due to [formControl] in children

Comment: let factory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyFormComponent);
    let compRef = this.formSlotRef.createComponent(factory);
    compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()  , This also resolve the error